# Make Element Visible in an overflow div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that is `overflow:hidden`, and on page load, that div is also `display:none`. It will only show when a button (`#showList`) is pressed. On page load, one of the `div.listelement`s will also have class `.selected`. What I need to be able to do, is on every click of that `button#showList`, the user should see the element with `.listelement.selected`. My existing code is below :

## HTML

---

```
<button id="showList">Select Family</button>
<div class="familylist">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <div data-id="###" class="button listelement">
        <h2 class="name">My Name</h2>
        <p class="address">My Address</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div data-id="###" class="button listelement">
        <h2 class="name">My Name</h2>
        <p class="address">My Address</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div data-id="###" class="button listelement selected">
        <h2 class="name">My Name</h2>
        <p class="address">My Address</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div data-id="###" class="button listelement">
        <h2 class="name">My Name</h2>
        <p class="address">My Address</p>
      </div>
    </li> ... 
  </ul>
</div>
```

## CSS

---

```
.familylist {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 214px;
    display:none
}
```

## (Relevant) JS

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".familylist .listelement[data-id=123]").addClass("selected").css("background-color","aliceblue");
});
```

---

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly8bh08s/1/) to show the problem. When you click the button for the first time, the blue element is not being shown. You can only see it when you scroll down. I'm wanting it to show in the visible area of the div when I click it.

Comment: On button click, do you want to show the entire `.familylist` or just the `.selected` child?

Comment: explanation of expected behavior isn't very clear. A demo in jsfiddle.net might help

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the question @charlietfl

Comment: can hide all others or set scrollTop based on the selected element position, not sure what is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a scrolling action to your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li[data-id='123']").addClass("selected");

    $("button").click(function(){

        $(".familylist").toggle();
        $(".familylist").scrollTop(210);

    });

});
```

Here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ly8bh08s/2/

Comment: how did you get the number 210? which one is selected will be dynamic.

Comment: Set an array with all values and according the selection, put the right value.

Comment: how would I get all the values anyway?

Comment: If your elements inside the scrollable area have all of them the same height, then you can also use that number (height) and multiply it by (the index of the element inside the scrollable area). Solutions are a lot, just be creative. The `scrollTop` will perfectly accomplish what I think you want: scrolling to the selected element.

Comment: alright. Is there a way to get the position of the element through jQuery though , or will I have to do math?

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6txxLeym/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".familylist .listelement[data-id=123]").addClass("selected").css("background-color", "aliceblue");
    $('#showList').click(function () {
        $('.familylist').show().find('.listelement:not(.selected)').parent().hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am understanding your intended behavior, here's how I'd approach it.

First, you'll want to move your data attribute and classes up into the li so that we can target the whole item. Otherwise, if we hide just the divs inside of the li, you'll see an empty list item (including the dot).

HTML:

```
<button id="showList">Select Family</button>
<div class="familylist">
  <ul class="list">
    <li data-id="###" class="button listelement">
      <div >
        <h2 class="name">My Name</h2>
        <p class="address">My Address</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li data-id="###" class="button listelement">
      <div >
        <h2 class="name">My Name</h2>
        <p class="address">My Address</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li data-id="###" class="button listelement selected">
      <div >
        <h2 class="name">My Name (Selected)</h2>
        <p class="address">My Address</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li data-id="###" class="button listelement">
      <div >
        <h2 class="name">My Name</h2>
        <p class="address">My Address</p>
      </div>
    </li> ... 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then, your CSS should not hide the entire family list if you want to show a child of it. The child will always be hidden if the parent is hidden. Just hide the list items:

```
.familylist {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 214px;
}
.familylist .listelement {
    display: none;
}
```

Finally, the jQuery to show the selected element on click:

```
$(".familylist .listelement[data-id=123]").addClass("selected").css("background-color","aliceblue");
$("#showList").on("click",function(){
    $(".listelement.selected").show();
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khbpe7eg/1/

Comment: Well I dont want to hide the element, i just want to scroll to it within the overflow div

Comment: Also the parent div is in an overlay, which is why its hidden on page load and is shown in the overlay on button click @JoshKG

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the question @JoshKG. Maybe that will help communicate the problem correctly